# Laravel 5, can't insert via request method doesn't exist

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-routing

That's what i'm trying to do without any success:

In welcome.blade I have a foreach with some boards and subboards(random generated by user) where you can click on subboard and go something like this /subboardOne. I got this on my routes.php

```
Route::get('/{subboaName}', 'ThreadController@index');
Route::post('/{subboaName}', 'ThreadController@store');
```

then you can post a thread on this subboard via form but since i really don't know how laravel knows where he is, the form is something like this:

```
<form class="form col-md-12 center-block" role="form" method="POST" action="/{{$subboardcoll->id}}">
```

this $subboardcoll->id comes from the controller, where it sends via the index function the collection:

```
public function index($subboard)
{
    $subboardcoll = Subboard::where('subboaName', $subboard)->first();
    $threads = Thread::where('subboaId', $subboardcoll->id)
           ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
           ->get();
    return view('threads.thread', compact('threads', 'subboardcoll'));
}
```

then i'm trying to send my form and store the thread autoinserting the subboardId but laravel doesn't recognize subboards method:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'comentario' => 'required|max:2000',
            //'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|recaptcha',
            //'imagen' => 'required',
        ]);

        $request->subboards()->threads()->create([
            'thrName' => $request->nombre,
            'thrComment' => $request->comentario,
            'thrImg' => $request->imagen,
            'thrSubject' => $request->tema,
        ]);

        return redirect()->back();

    }
```

And gives me this erorr:

```
BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 81: Method subboards does not exist.
```

Can you guys helpme to know why? also is there better form to do what i'm trying? im newbie on laravel, thanks

EDIT:

Thread.php

```
public function subboard()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Subboard::class, 'subboaId');
}
```

Subboard.php

```
public function thread()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Thread::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method subboards do not exist in a request object. Consider doing this

```
public function store($id, Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'comentario' => 'required|max:2000',
        //'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|recaptcha',
        //'imagen' => 'required',
    ]);

   Subboard::find($id)->threads()->create([
        'thrName' => $request->nombre,
        'thrComment' => $request->comentario,
        'thrImg' => $request->imagen,
        'thrSubject' => $request->tema,
    ]);

   //Alternative query statement
   Subboard::where('id', $id)->first()->threads()->create([.....

    return redirect()->back();

}
```

Comment: Did that, passing an id through form but when executing it gives me that error:

Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::columnize() must be of the type array, string given, called in E:\laragon\www\DeepElite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 121 and defined

Comment: Sorry about that made the incorrect reference. When using find you only pass the $id. I have edited my answer to reflect correct usage.

Comment: Seems like threads() it's a undefined method, dunno why because on my models it's all fine, edditing my question